# Can a constant repulsive interaction( between nearest neighbor) on a 1 dimensional chain cause a stripe phase?

Tags: condensed-matter, variational-principle, correlation-functions

I am confused about how to spontaneously  separate a 1 dimensional chain into different component, can a constant short range repulsive interaction between the nearest neighbor works, I use variational principles and the numerical results tells that it can't. but I am doubt of it. I see in paper PRA 92,053623. A stripe like phase can be formed in ladder lattice. so why can' t it works in a one dimensional chain.